# Quickest and easiest way to refresh your memory about .NET and SQL

Tags: .net, sql

I haven't touched .NET and SQL in a while and I will need to go abroad in 10 days and work on these technologies. I don't need to learn them from scratch since I was quite familiar with these languages a year or two ago. What I would like to know is how can I refresh my memory after all this time in just 10 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come up with an application that you think would be fun to create, use .NET and SQL to do it. Learn by doing.

Answer (score 1):

Get a fast-track intro book that you can chew up and spit out, and then see if you need to learn more.

I recommend "Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes (3rd Edition)".  The Sams Teach Yourself series is great at getting you refreshed on a topic quickly.  I highly recommend them to get ramped up quickly, and then find 900 page reference materials later to answer your advanced questions down the road.

Also try 
[D-Zone's Refcardz](http://refcardz.dzone.com/).  They have many quick intro's to .NET topics.